# Singular/Plural dilemma in given context

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

The writers in that department write like they never read a book in their **lives**.

The writers in that department write like they never read a book in their **life**.

Is the second sentence grammatically correct? Even though the rules of grammar suggest the first is the sentence one should choose, is the second sentence acceptable?

Comment: Logically, you might think that since "they" here are plural "writers", the reference should be to their "**lives**". But note this typical usage: [*The men always wore a nice dark suit and tie with a hat on their head.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22they+never%22+%22with+a+hat+on+their+head%22) Lots of native speakers don't care about "consistency of plurality" in such contexts - especially when the intended meaning is obvious (we know we're talking about what each individual writer has or hasn't done in his *individual life*). Consider ***We all** raised our right **hand**.*

Comment: I would say that  "*We all raised our right hand*" is simply wrong, although not too uncommon an error. It should be either "We all raised our right **hands**" or "We each raised our right hand."

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Everyone has their own stories" vs "Everyone has their own story" - which one is correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105868/everyone-has-their-own-stories-vs-everyone-has-their-own-story-which-one-i)

Comment: Writers is plural. Their is plural, and so it must be "lives" plural.

Answer (score 0):

No, the second sentence is never acceptable. "Writers" is plural, so "their lives" must be plural.

Note however that if you were using the *gender-neutral singular "they"* to refer to a person of unknown, irrelevant, or non-binary gender, the singular "life" would be appropriate, to match with the (in that case) singular "writer."